# Python: create dictionary inside dictionary to convert to JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to create the JSON:

```
[
    {
        measurement: "Equipment1",
        fields: {
            Pressure: 5.5
        },
        tags:{
            MachineType:"type1"
        },
        timestamp: 1530717056.48
    }
]
```

The code ive written is :

```
import json
import time
from decimal import Decimal

count = 0
read_pressures = []
while (count < 100):
    current_time=time.time()
    array_of_pressures.append(dict(measurement="Equipment1", dict(pressure=5.5),dict(MachineType="Type1"),timestamp=time.time()))
    time.sleep(0.01)
    count = count + 1
    print(data) #
    read_pressures.append(data)
print ("printing all values")
print(json.dumps(read_pressures, ensure_ascii=False))
#print(read_pressures)
```

The codes giving a error "SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
" but i dont know how i'm supposed to create a dictionary inside a dictionary. Any help appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: What is `array_of_pressures`? What is `data`?

Comment: `dict(pressure=5.5)` is a different key in a parent `dict`, write instead `fields=dict(pressure=5.5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dict(measurement="Equipment1", dict(pressure=5.5),dict(MachineType="Type1"),timestamp=time.time()))
```

Here, you are missing key names ("fields" and "tags") for some of the dictionary values.

```
dict(measurement="Equipment1", fields=dict(pressure=5.5), tags=dict(MachineType="Type1"), timestamp=time.time()))
```

Or you can write it more simply as

```
data = { "measurement": "Equipment1",
         "fields": { "pressure": 5.5 },
         "tags": { "MachineType": "Type1" },
         "timestamp": time.time()
       }
```

As tobias_k points out, you also seem to be trying to append your dict to something called `array_of_pressures`, which is not created anywhere in your code, instead of simply assigning your dict to `data`.

Comment: Also, instead of appending to a non-existing list, the line should probably be `data = dict(...)`